# Passing multiple editText field data to another activity

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext

I want if the user enters data in any one field then it's value passes to other activity and other edittext fields don't pass their values. But when I can add all editText string values l, intent sends all values. I want only those values which have data and other values won't be sent. I can pass data with `Intent.createchooser`

**Xml:**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/student_name_sixClass_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:hint="Student name"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/english_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="English"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/math_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Math"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sciece_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Science"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/urdu_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Urdu"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/islamiyat_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Islamiyat"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ps_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="P.S"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/history_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="History"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/computer_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Computer"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/geography_six_sub_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                android:hint="Geography"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/sixClass_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/monthly_test_report_radioBtn_sixClass"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Monthly Test Report"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/weekly_test_report_radioBtn_sixClass"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Weekly Test Report"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendBtn_six"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/btn_color"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Java code:**

```
 sendBtn_six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isValid()){
            

       Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
                sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ANMOL ACEDMY OF SCIENCE\n" + "Asslam_O_Alaikum!" + "\n" + "Repert: " + slct_monthly_reprottext + "\n" + "Field: " + slct_biology_field_nineScience + "\n" + "On Dated: " + current_date+"\n" + "Student Name: " + student_name_nineScience
                        + "\n" + "English: " + engilish_nine_science_sub + "\n" + "Math: " + math_nine_science_sub + "\n" + "Urdu: " + urdu_nine_science_sub
                        + "\n" + "Islamiyat: " + islamiyat_nine_science_sub + "\n" + "P.S: " + ps_nine_science_sub + "\n" + "Chemistry: " + chemistry_nine_science_sub
                        + "\n" + "computer: " + computer_nine_science_sub + "\n" + "Physics: " + physics_nine_science_sub
                        + "\n" + "Regards: Anmol Acedmy of Science");
//
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent sendData = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, null);
                startActivity(sendData);
                }
            }
        });
```

**I want if user wants to add data in some fields then clicks the button, the data can pass to other application**

Answer (score 1):

Parse all your EditTexts and get their values by calling `yourEditTextView.getText()`.

I assume you bind your views first:

```
EditText mathSix = findViewById(R.id.math_six_sub_editText);

String mathSixSub = mathSix.getText();
```

This method returns the string of the EditText or `null` if the EditText is empty. Then add it to the intent you've created accordingly, or if you want to send the data to an activity within your app use a simple Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this, theActivityThatReceivesTheData.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, "Math Six: " + mathSixSub);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to. add an empty space where the values are null, you can add the following nullity check instead:

```
String mathSixSub = mathSix.getText() == null ? " " : mathSix.getText();
```

this operator checks if the `EditText` is null and adds a space to where the text would have been, otherwise it adds the text that's in the view.